# Table indexing and member binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm

In the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/ueP5U/1/

i have a table in which every td/th member is given a relative index by its `<tr>`

```
var tableIterator = function(table, process) {
$.each(table.children(), function() { //cycle through thead,tbody,tfoot
    $(this).children().each(function() { //cycle through thead, tbody, tfoot "tr"s
        process.call($(this));
    });
});
}



tableIterator($("table"), function() {
  $(this).find("td,th").each(function() {
    $(this).text("Index: " + $(this).index()); 
  });
});
```

​

The table can contain two or more headers where the parent header gets a bigger colspan and the bottom header conforms by giving the equivalent amount of columns (i.e index 4 has two children indexed 1 and 2).

What i'm actually trying to do is to make the parent header, select all its 'children' (not actual dom children of course), and make the same action based on the selected column.

I got the logic down: each header element, needs to find its previous sibling 'children' indexes and add the amount of colspan to its own children ot get their indexes (i.e index 5[colspan=2], going to index 4, finding its last child (index 1)) and adding the amount of colspans to its 'children' so they will have index: 2 and index: 3 (+=1*colspan.val() times)

same goes with it's tbody 'children'.

i assume that i need to create an object array containing the bind elements according to whatever is shown using jQuery.filter(return $("thead").findByColumn(2[or any other top header index]))

would love some assistance since i'm having trouble even beginning this, examples with highlight by click, hiding by max_width or running things on columns according to selections are more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
function iterTable(table, callback) {
    // Keeps track of which indices are blocked by larger cells
    var blocked = [];

    $("thead,tbody,tfoot", table).each(function (groupIndex) {
        var groupName = this.tagName;

        $("tr", this).each(function (rowIndex) {
            var colIndex = 0;
            var blockedRow = blocked[0] || [];

            $("td,th", this).each(function () {
                var $cell = $(this);
                var colSpan = parseInt($cell.prop("colspan")) || 1;
                var rowSpan = parseInt($cell.prop("rowspan")) || 1;

                // Skip all blocked cells
                while (blockedRow[colIndex]) {
                    colIndex++;
                }

                callback(groupIndex, groupName, rowIndex, colIndex, $cell);

                // Mark all sub-cells as blocked.
                for (var i = 0; i < rowSpan; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < colSpan; j++) {
                        if (!blocked[i]) blocked[i] = [];
                        blocked[i][colIndex+j] = true;
                    }
                }
                colIndex += colSpan;
            });

            // Pop the first element; We don't need it any more.
            blocked.shift();
        });
    });
}

var columns = [];
iterTable($('table'), function (groupIndex, groupName, rowIndex, colIndex, $cell) {
    $cell.text(groupName + " " + rowIndex + "," + colIndex);
    if (groupName == "TBODY") {

        // Save the cell into a specific column.
        if (!columns[colIndex]) columns[colIndex] = [];
        columns[colIndex][rowIndex] = $cell;

    }
    else { // THEAD or TFOOT

        var colSpan = parseInt($cell.prop("colspan")) || 1;
        $cell.click(function () {
            // Toggle the background for the column under the header.
            for (var i = 0; i < colSpan; i++) {
                $.each(columns[colIndex+i], function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                });
            }
        });

    }
});
```

[(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ueP5U/2/)

Comment: Hi Markus and thank you for your comment - i guess i didn't mention that i'd like to combine all its children which also means the th's below the more than 1 colspan th (ie-THEAD(1,6)&THEAD(1,7) with THEAD(0,6))
I've achieved what you achieved with something like:var hideItems = function(removeIndex,table){  tableIterator(table,function(){    if(!$(this).parents("thead").hasClass("cols-hidden")) {$(this).find(".toggle-view:lt("+removeIndex+")").not(function(){ return $(this).data("colspan")==5 }).hide().parents("thead").addClass("cols-hidden");}});};
using a class instead of your blocked[] arr